# How do I delete sculpting brushes in 2.8?

Tags: interface, sculpting

I downloaded a popular sculpting brush pack and included/appended it in my default startup file.

The textures somehow went missing. How can I delete the, now useless, brushes from my project?

[image: missing buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it in the tools panels, not in the toolbar for some reasons:

[image]